# Key-Combination to add braces in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Using C# Visual Studio 2010, I have just accidentally added braces to an else statement - it was a complete accident, and I haven't got a clue what key-combinations did it.

The code I had was this...

```
if (data.Name != "")
    cmdUpdateData.Parameters["@NAME"].Value = data.Name;
else
    cmdUpdateData.Parameters["@NAME"].Value = DBNull.Value;
```

The cursor was at the end of the `else` statement, and when I did the accidental key combination the result was...

```
if (data.Name != "")
    cmdUpdateData.Parameters["@NAME"].Value = data.Name;
else
{

}
cmdUpdateData.Parameters["@NAME"].Value = DBNull.Value;
```

... with the cursor now between the braces and indented to the correct level.

I cannot replicate it, and I cannot work out what I did to do this (I can type too quickly for my own good at times).

Does anybody know what combination does this, where it's defined, or where there is a list of similar combinations?

Comment: Enter, open brace, enter, enter, close brace. :)

Comment: Thanks @Cathal, yes I'm already aware of this "key-combination", but I didn't type an open brace.  (I'm guessing your smilie recognises that it wasn't as simple as that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a ReSharper installed then you probably used the `else` [code snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx) by pressing `Tab` key.

[image]

---

If you have ReSharper installed then:

You pressed **Shift + Enter** instead of just enter. This will put curly braces at the end of `else`. I have been able to reproduce this for only `else` statement so far, it doesn't put curly braces for `if` block or for a method.

For a list of shortcut keys see: [Default Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Habib.  Strangely, I don't seem to be able to reproduce it, shift+enter simply gives me a new line

Comment: Are you pressing shift + Enter after type `else` and a space ? Just type `else` without any space and then press shift + enter

Comment: I've tried typing `else` both with and without a space.  I've tried pressing shift+enter straight after typing, and going back after writing the entire statement.  I just can't replicate it.  The page you've linked to actually shows shift+enter as just `Edit.BreakLine`

Comment: @freefaller, just realized one more thing, with default setting you probably used the code snippet for `else` which is used by pressing `Tab` key.

Comment: BINGO @Habib... it was `Tab`, as I don't have re-sharper.  Thank you!!